# Is there a way to limit cpu usage according to my clusters current resources?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to limit a specific namespace to never leave less then a full cpu for my other namespaces (using a resources quota) and i have to problems in the way.:
a. Today i find the total amount of cpus using `kubectl top nodes` and divide the nominal cpu usage in the usage percentages, this is not accurate enough, is there a way to get my cluster total available cpu?
b. I would like to dynamically adjust to changes in the cluster (specifically added or removed nodes), a cronjob works fine but I'm looking for a way to hook major nodes changes, is there a known way to do that?

Comment: Number of nodes CPUs is under `.status.capacity.cpu`. You can print them e.g. with `kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CPU:.status.capacity.cpu`. Dynamicaly adding/removing nodes can be achieved using [autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler). Does this answer your question?

Comment: yes, seems like it -  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. You can set namespace level quotas easily enough but to make it that kind of dynamic thing you would need to make an operator or similar. A simple version would be a script running as a cron job which updates the Quota object.

Answer (score 0):

Number of nodes CPUs is under `.status.capacity.cpu` in node object. You can print them e.g. with `kubectl get nodes -o custom-columns=NAME:.metadata.name,CPU:.status.capacity.cpu`.

Dynamicaly adding/removing nodes can be achieved using [autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler).